# Why php .htacess redirect blog directory to home page

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am facing a issue.below is my site 
 http://www.wellnessvisit.com/

and also I have blog folder where I install wordpress, the site other urls working fine but when I click to http://www.wellnessvisit.com/blog/

my page redirect to http://www.wellnessvisit.com/

while I want to redirect to http://www.wellnessvisit.com/blog/.

**Root .htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule doctor-(.*)\.htm$ doctor-details.php?doc_id=$1
RewriteRule hospital-(.*)\.htm$ hospital_detail.php?hosp_spec_id=$1
RewriteRule hotel-(.*)\.htm$ hotel_details.php?hotel_id=$1
RewriteRule destination-(.*)\.htm$ destination_details.php?dest_id=$1
RewriteRule news-(.*)\.htm$ news-details.php?news_id=$1
RewriteRule article-(.*)\.htm$ articles-details.php?article=$1
RewriteRule service-(.*)\.htm$ service-details.php?service_id=$1
RewriteRule user-register.php$ register.php 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
#adds ".php" to a URL that isn't a directory or a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)$ $1.php
```

**Wordpress .htaccess file**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: In blog wordpress, check the site url

Comment: @TamilSelvan the site url is fine

Comment: You are testing with permanent redirects. A previous attempt is likely cached, as when I visit that url the redirect does not take place. I am therefore closing this as not reproducable.